# Is it possible to set SPI slave mode on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

The purpose of this project is to send at least 1Msps EMI data samples from STM32F4 discovery board to Raspberry Pi (RPI) through SPI. In general, the RPI could only act as master mode. In this case, I tried py-spiDev, only less than 30Ksps could be generated. Is it possible to set SPI slave mode on RPI? In this way, I can set stm32f4 to master mode, set ADC to scan mode and enable DMA-SPI to send data stream directly to RPI.

could anyone show some example codes?

Comment: Afaik **no**, see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/can-raspberry-pi-function-as-spi-slave/36173#36173